# generate 9 byte alphunumeric from a seed of 10 digits number

Tags: random, uniqueidentifier

I have a unique 10 digits phone number, I want to generate a 9 character unique alphanumeric id from it. It doesn't need to be reversible, but the same unique alphanumeric id should be generated from the same phone number.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself. On the one hand you say that you want to generate *unique* alphanumeric identifiers from the phone numbers and then you say that "it doesn't need to be reversible". If the identifiers are unique then the mapping is reversible (by brute-force if nothing else). In any event: 1) what programming language? 2) what have you tried?

Comment: For uniqueness try using some form of encryption; different inputs are guaranteed to produce unique outputs.  For the alphanumeric output try using a Base32 conversion of the encrypted input.  Do not treat the phone number as characters, but as an integer, that will reduce the bit size of the encryption needed.  Look at Format Preserving Encryptions for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility. It gives a unique 9-character alphanumeric identifier to all numbers in the range 0 to 9999999999 in such a way that the inverse is not easily computable (with only 10 billion possible numbers genuine security is impossible, but it is easy enough to make it difficult for casual users). It is based on modular exponentiation using a primitive root mod `p`, where `p` is a prime chosen to be larger than `10^10`:

1) First add 1 to the number to make sure that it isn't 0

2) Then raise the primitive root to this number, mod `p`. This is easy to do
   with modular exponentiation by squaring

3) Write the result in hex

4) Pad by `'X'` if the result has fewer than `9` digits.

Here is a Python implementation:

```
p = 10000000259 #prime
a = 17 #primitive root mod p

#assumes num is an integer in range 0 to 9999999999:

def unique_id(num):
    num += 1 #so num is in range 1 to p-1
    num = pow(a,num,p)
    h = hex(num)[2:]
    return (h + 'x'*(9 - len(h))).upper()
```

For example:

```
>>> unique_id(12024561111) #White House phone number
'1614351BX'
```

A non-brute force attack would need to solve the base-17 [discrete log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem (mod 10000000259). This isn't particularly hard but is non-trivial and is probably adequate to dissuade casual attempts to recover the original number. You could replace `p` by another prime (and `a` by a corresponding primitive root), as long as `p > 10^10` and the hex-representation of `p-1` is 9 hex digits or less in length. If the conversion from numbers to identifiers is kept server-side then a casual attacker wouldn't have access to `a` and `p`, which would add a layer of "security through obscurity" (dubious security, but better than nothing).